# Vue 2: are template-based functional components as performant as render functions?

Tags: performance, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-functional-component

In Vue 2.5.0+ we have two different ways of implementing functional components: `<template functional>` and using a render function. However, I've always wondered: are both ways actually equally performant?

Comment: It's very easy to test. Make a Vue instance and feed it the same component until it breaks. Say 1 mil instances. Than change it to be the other type. Time them with `performance.now()` differences. See which one takes longer to render/breaks faster. Don't quote me on this, but I believe functional components use render function under the hood. In practice it might be insignificantly slower with `<template functional>`.